# Search with regex - is there a way to find classes that do not have a certain annotation in any of its methods?

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

I want to look in a certain directory and find in all of its sub directories all of the classes that derive from X and do not have annotation Y.

If this isn't possible, I can manage with all classes that do not contain annotation Y.

Is that possible with the regex search?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible. But it's possible to find classes that do not have given annotation (works only if class have only one annotation):

Regex: `@(?!Annotation.*)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using Structural Search. Use a pattern like this:

```
@$Y$
class $A$ extends $X$ {}
```

Edit Variables:
X - text/regexp: `X`, `Apply constraint within type hierarchy` checked to find indirect subclasses
Y - text/regexp: `Y`, min/max occurrences: `0`

To search a specific directory only, you will have to create a custom scope.